# How to add update function to ID-Property

Tags: scripting

I want to create and integer Integer ID-Property and assign Update function to it

Comment: you should probably ask ' is it possible to give an ID-property an update function' ? .. because I don't think it is.

Comment: Maybe expand/clarify your question a bit. Where do you want the property, some sample code that you want to work.